# Add PHP code to block's content

Tags: 8, blocks

Is there a module that allows a php text filter in drupal 8? This was a possibility in drupal-7 but I can not find something similar to 8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PHP filter module was [removed from core](https://www.drupal.org/node/2088811), because of the inherent security problems it presents.

It now exists as a [separate contrib module](https://www.drupal.org/project/php), but beware that even the module description itself warns against using it:

> **Warning**
>
> Enabling this module can cause security and performance issues as it allows users to execute PHP code on your site. There are better alternatives out there that do not expose such vulnerabilities on your site.

Comment: I guess the better alternative would be to create a custom module that creates a custom block.

Comment: `even the module description itself warns against using it` yet you're recommending it? :O

Comment: @NoSssweat Nope, not recommending, just informing :)